# committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to process an XML file and save the related properties of the file to an EF code first database and I have the following logic:

```
 Process Market Message 
 Process MessageType342
 Process Meter Level
 Process Channel Information Level
 Process Interval Information Level
```

In order to move to the next step I need to attach the Entity to my context and then save changes as each level requires a foreign key value to be added from the previous level but when I try the following process as shown in the code below I get the error message having saved the 2nd MessageType342 it errors out with the following message:

**The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.**

My code is as follows:

**Process MessageType342**

```
Private Function ProcessMessageType342(ByVal doc As XmlDocument, ByVal marketMessage As MarketMessage)

    'Reset the node list to appropriate message type
    Dim xmlRootNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("MY_VALUE")
    xmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SUBLEVEL")

    'Declare Variable for the Non Interval Technical Meter Detailss
    Dim MessageType342 = New messageType342

    'Declare and Initialize the attributes ExportIntervalMeterDailyReadings
    Dim attr1 = ""
    Dim attr2 = ""
    Dim attr3 = ""
    Dim attr4 = ""
    Dim attr5 = ""
    Dim attr6 = ""
    Dim attr7 = ""

    'Iterate through the nodes
    For i = 0 To xmlNodeList.Count - 1
        'Iterate through the possible attributes of MessageType342
        For j = 0 To xmlNodeList(i).Attributes.Count - 1
            'Set the relevant variable according to the header attributes
            Select Case xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Name
                Case "attr1" : attr1 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
                Case "attr2" : attr2 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
                Case "attr3" : attr3 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
                Case "attr4" : attr4 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
                Case "attr5" : attr5 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
                Case "attr6" : attr6 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
                Case "attr7" : attr7 = xmlNodeList(i).Attributes(j).Value
            End Select
        Next

        'Set the Mandatory Values for MessageType342
        MessageType342.MarketMessageID = marketMessage.MarketMessageID
        MessageType342.attr1 = attr1
        MessageType342.attr2 = attr2
        MessageType342.attr3 = attr3
        MessageType342.attr4 = attr4

        'Set the Optional Values for MessageType342
        If (Not attr5 = "") Then
            MessageType342.attr5 = attr5
        End If
        If (Not attr6 = "") Then
            MessageType342.attr6 = attr6
        End If
        If (Not attr7 = "") Then
            MessageType342.attr7 = attr7
        End If

        'Add MessageType342 class to database context
        db.MessageTypes342.Add(MessageType342)
        db.SaveChanges()

        'Process the Meter for each of the Sub Level Infos
        For k = 0 To xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes.Count - 1
            Select Case xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(k).Name
                Case "MeterID" : ProcessMeters(xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(k), marketMessage, MessageType342.messageType342ID)
            End Select
        Next
    Next

    'Process the Message Trailers
    xmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("MessageTrailer")
    For i = 0 To xmlNodeList.Count - 1
        ProcessMessageTrailers2(xmlNodeList(i), marketMessage, MessageType342.messageType342ID)
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

**Process Meter Level**

```
 Private Function ProcessMeters(ByVal node As XmlNode, ByVal marketMessage As MarketMessage, ByVal messageTypeID As Integer)
    If node.Attributes.Count = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        'Declare Variables
        Dim Meter = New Meter
        Dim MeterCategoryCode = ""
        Dim SerialNumber = ""
        Dim MeterLocationCode = ""

        For i = 0 To node.Attributes.Count - 1

            'Set the relevant variable according to the meter attributes
            Select Case node.Attributes(i).Name

                Case "MeterCategoryCode" : MeterCategoryCode = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "SerialNumber" : SerialNumber = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "MeterLocationCode" : MeterLocationCode = node.Attributes(i).Value

            End Select

        Next

        'Create new CustomerContactDetail entity and set the mandatory values
        Meter.SerialNumber = SerialNumber

        'Set the optional values
        If (Not MeterCategoryCode = "") Then
            Meter.MeterCategoryCode = MeterCategoryCode
        End If

        'Set the optional values
        If (Not MeterLocationCode = "") Then
            Meter.MeterLocationCode = MeterLocationCode
        End If

        'Set the relevant message type ID depending on the message type of the header
        'Dim mm As MarketMessage = db.MarketMessages.[Single](Function(_mm) _mm.MarketMessageID = marketMessageID)
        'Dim mmt As MarketMessageType = db.MarketMessageTypes.[Single](Function(_mmt) _mmt.Header = mm.messageType)

        'Select Case mmt.MarketMessageTypeID
        Select Case marketMessage.messageType
            Case "341" : Meter.MessageType341ID = messageTypeID 'Type341
            Case "342" : Meter.MessageType342ID = messageTypeID 'Type342
        End Select

        'Add Meter class to database context
        db.Meters.Add(Meter)
        db.SaveChanges()

        For j = 0 To node.ChildNodes.Count - 1

            Select Case node.ChildNodes(j).Name

                Case "RegisterLevelInfo" : ProcessRegisterLevelInfo(node.ChildNodes(j), "Meters", Meter.MeterID)
                Case "ChannelInfo" : ProcessChannelInfo(node.ChildNodes(j), "Meters", Meter.MeterID)
                Case "SupplierProvidedRead" : ProcessSupplierProvidedReads(node.ChildNodes(j), Meter.MeterID)

            End Select

        Next
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

**Process Channel Level**

```
 Private Function ProcessChannelInfo(ByVal node As XmlNode, ByVal meterType As String, ByVal meterID As Integer)
    If node.Attributes.Count = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        'Declare Mandatory Variables
        Dim ChannelInformation = New ChannelInformation
        Dim MeteringInterval = ""
        Dim RegisterTypeCode = ""
        Dim UOM_Code = ""

        For i = 0 To node.Attributes.Count - 1

            'Set the relevant variable according to the register level information attributes
            Select Case node.Attributes(i).Name

                Case "MeteringInterval" : MeteringInterval = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "RegisterTypeCode" : RegisterTypeCode = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "UOM_Code" : UOM_Code = node.Attributes(i).Value

            End Select

        Next

        'Create new RegisterLevelInformation entity and set the mandatory values
        'ChannelInformation.MeterID = CType(meterID, Integer)
        ChannelInformation.MeteringInterval = CType(MeteringInterval, Integer)
        ChannelInformation.RegisterTypeCode = RegisterTypeCode
        ChannelInformation.UOM_Code = UOM_Code

        'Set the type of meter to which this belongs
        Select Case meterType

            Case "Meters" : ChannelInformation.MeterID = meterID
            Case "RemovedMeters" : ChannelInformation.RemovedMeterRegisterID = meterID
            Case "NewMeters" : ChannelInformation.NewMeterRegisterID = meterID
            Case "RetainedMeters" : ChannelInformation.RetainedMeterRegisterID = meterID

        End Select

        'Add Meter class to database context
        db.ChannelInformations.Add(ChannelInformation)
        db.SaveChanges()

        For j = 0 To node.ChildNodes.Count - 1

            Select Case node.ChildNodes(j).Name

                Case "IntervalInfo" : ProcessIntervalInfo(node.ChildNodes(j), ChannelInformation.ChannelInformationID)

            End Select

        Next

        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

**Process Interval Info Level**

```
 Private Function ProcessIntervalInfo(ByVal node As XmlNode, ByVal channelID As Integer)
    If node.Attributes.Count = 0 Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        'Declare Mandatory Variables
        Dim IntervalInformation = New IntervalInformation
        Dim IntervalValue = ""
        Dim IntervalPeriodTimestamp = ""
        Dim IntervalStatusCode = ""
        Dim NetActiveDemandValue = ""

        For i = 0 To node.Attributes.Count - 1

            'Set the relevant variable according to the register level information attributes
            Select Case node.Attributes(i).Name

                Case "IntervalValue" : IntervalValue = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "IntervalPeriodTimestamp" : IntervalPeriodTimestamp = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "IntervalStatusCode" : IntervalStatusCode = node.Attributes(i).Value
                Case "NetActiveDemandValue" : NetActiveDemandValue = node.Attributes(i).Value

            End Select

        Next

        'Create new RegisterLevelInformation entity and set the mandatory values
        IntervalInformation.ChannelInformationID = CType(channelID, Integer)
        IntervalInformation.IntervalValue = CType(IntervalValue, Decimal)
        IntervalInformation.IntervalPeriodTimestamp = IntervalPeriodTimestamp
        IntervalInformation.IntervalStatusCode = IntervalStatusCode

        'Set the optional values
        If (Not NetActiveDemandValue = "") Then
            IntervalInformation.NetActiveDemandValue = CType(NetActiveDemandValue, Decimal)
        End If


        'Add IntervalInformation class to database context
        db.IntervalInformations.Add(IntervalInformation)
        db.SaveChanges()

        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Jay  Do you by chance have another relationship between the 'tables' that you've overlooked.  I had this sort of thing before with EF and often as not there were other dependencies that I'd either forgotten about completely or simply overlooked setting a value for.

Comment: No Dom I haven't overlooked any dependencies, I have checked this to be double sure, i think my problem might be the means as to how i am attaching the entity to the context